# Laravel project within another laravel project

Tags: php, .htaccess, laravel, laravel-5

I have project which is built with laravel 3.

Currently, I made another products using Laravel 5.2.

Is it possible to have Laravel 5.2 within Laravel 3. HOST do not care what framework is used.

[image]

In this case we have two ROUTES.

Both uses same DB.

It would be real nice if we could do this:

http://aaaa.com/ is the main application which is redirected to public_html

and is it possible to do this:

http://aaaa.com/laravel5/ is the application in Laravel 5.2 redirect to public.

What do I have to do in .htaccess?

any help would be nice

Comment: Why won't you just port the project to laravel 5? Laravel 3 is very outdated.

Comment: @CharlotteDunois I know what you mean. but the system was built using L3 and we are planning to convert to L5 in the future. until then I need this solution

Comment: One thing is clear, what you are trying to do is tough. The only option I can suggest is API. You  can build and API in L3 and consume it in L5, still need lots of work to achieve that. I believe migrating L3 to L5 is a quicker and better option

Comment: @Digitlimit One thing I need to be little clear. We have .htaccess and Route.

.htaccess can be redirected to public_html (L3), Cant we have something like?

http://aaaa.com/laravel5/ in .htaccess redirect to public (L5) ?

Comment: Good point. Depends on your .htaccess rules. Laravel request lifecycle starts from `public/index.php`. You can trying writing a rule that loads `Laravel5/public/index.php` located in L5 when a certain Route is visited in L3

Comment: Would it be an option to make the L5 a sub-domain instead? so laravel5.aaaa.com?